# JSF increment value bean

Tags: java, jsf, increment

I want to increment The `score` property in my bean with a `selectOneRadio`.

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{quizBean.score}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{q.answers}" var="a" itemLabel="#{a.textAnswer}" itemValue="#{a.nbr}" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

like `value+="#{quizBean.score}"`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are looking to add one to the score?
Try:

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{quizBean.score + 1}">
```

or if you'd like the expression to be evaluated immediately use the ${} aka:

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="${quizBean.score + 1}">
```

See the documentation at [this link here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahu.html#bnahy)